# Gimp installed via snap has missing fonts and theme

Tags: themes, fonts, snap, gimp

I installed gimp via `snap install` previously and even though window decorations were missing, I was still able to use it. Today however, I opened up gimp and it's completely unusable (fonts is missing it seems).

See the screenshot attached.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tested the GIMP package on my machine by installing it via snap and here are my results :
[Fonts are working properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21331.png)

The fonts are working fine and they're not missing.
However it might be a possibility that something's broken.
What you can do is firstly remove the existing package from your machine 
using the following command

`sudo snap remove gimp`

Then reinstall GIMP using the following command

`sudo snap install gimp`

Also, if you've multiple packages installed (that is a previous installation of GIMP and also the snapcraft version) then you will have to launch GIMP from the snap directory like so `/snap/bin/gimp`

Another thing that I've come across is that there's an issue inside the font package and it's a fatal issue. 
Inside the package, PANGO gives warnings related to font-face and scaled-font.
Then LibGimpBASE gave a warning and then the application crashed due to a segmentation fault.

So, not exactly the issue that you've been facing but surely an issue with the fonts.

I'll raise an issue ticket regarding the same.

Till then try the above steps and let me know if it helps.